# Revising WHERE statement to include/exclude certain patients

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

2 similar SQL Server problems:

db_members is a member-level table classified by patient_id, provider_id and level_of_care_id.

The objective is to pull patients from differing levels of aggregation.

In the first query, we want to extract all patients from these 6 levels of care but for LOC 100.007 we need to exclude patients from one provider_id ('119282’);

In the second query, we want to extract all patients from these 6 levels of care but for LOC 100.007 we need to include only provider_id ('119282’) patients;

(This is a simplified version of the query)

```
select patient_id, provider_id, level_of_care_cd, 
from db_members 
where  level_of_care_cd in ('100.001', '100.004', '100.007', '100.022', '100.034', '100.037')      
group by level_of_care_cd, provider_id
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post sample data and desired results in text format, preferrably including DDL and DML statements so we can use them to quickly duplicate your data on our local instances which helps us help you.

Comment: Something like `where  level_of_care_cd in ('100.001', '100.004', '100.022', '100.034', '100.037') OR (level_of_care = '100.007' AND provider_id <> '119282')` should get you in the ballpark. Adjust accordingly for your second query

Comment: Try again. You posted a single query but your text says there are two queries. Why are you GROUPing with no aggregates? And lastly, phrases like "these 6 levels of care" don't mean anything to most people. If you use an acronym that is business-related, define it. Mind-reading doesn't work at a distance.

Comment: The original question described two queries but they are similar except one is to include selected members and the other one is to exclude selected members.  The code was simplified from a larger query where the grouping statement was needed;  please ignore that piece.  The query code clearly shows 6 levels of care;  I don't think most people would be mystified by what is meant.

Comment: I think JNevill is on the right track;  I will validate the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    select case when level_of_care_cd ='100.007' and
       patient_id not in (Select patient_id from patients where 
      provider_id='119282')
        then patient_id end as patient_id 
      , provider_id, 
       level_of_care_cd, 
       from db_members 
      where  level_of_care_cd in ('100.001', '100.004', '100.022', ' 
     '100.007`,   100.034', '100.037')       
      group by level_of_care_cd, provider_id
```

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation in addition to (hopefully) working code.

Answer (score 0):

**Exclude a provider with one LOC**

```
where level_of_care_cd in ( <full list> )
    and not (level_of_care_cd = '100.007' and provider_id = '119282')
```

This is equivalent as long as nulls don't come into play:

```
where level_of_care_cd in ( <full list> )
    and (level_of_care_cd <> '100.007' or provider_id <> '119282')
```

**Allow one provider with one LOC**

Be careful with nulls:

```
where level_of_care_cd in ( <full list> )
    and not (level_of_care_cd = '100.007' and provider_id <> '119282')

where level_of_care_cd in ( <full list> )
    and (level_of_care_cd <> '100.007' or provider_id = '119282')
```

The equivalencies are the result of De Morgan's Laws. The forms using `not` will probably read most naturally to the way people think. Remember that `or` has lower precedence than `and` so parentheses are important.